Error adding an organization to the network [Minifabric]
I'm having trouble adding an organization to an existing network.
I use the Minifabric tool to build a network and Docker to simulate the virtual environment.
I am following the steps in this tutorial.
In the last command (minifab nodeimport,join) an error is displayed:

I have already performed the operation of adding an organization in several ways, and have not been successful.
PS: using version 2.3 of Hyperleger Fabric (minifab -i 2.3) .
